# How this voltage resonant soft-switching IGBT works?

Tags: igbt

In this voltage resonant soft-switching IGBT:[image]

1) When IGBT turns off, what is the reason why Vce slowly(sinusoidally) increases after current turns off?

**Was it because the stored voltage in L1 is slowly discharged so that Vce will not abruptly increase???**

2)When IGBT turns on, what is the reason why Vce is zero when current is slowly increasing?
**I mean, if the Vce is zero at the moment of increasing current, then where is the remaining voltage is dropped in the circuit???And looking at the waveform, the Vce is already zero even if current is just starting to rise**

Source:https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/mosfet_igbt/igbt-013.html

Comment: 1) because the coil forms a resonant circuit with C1. 2) Vce goes to 0 volts when it turns on and the current through the inductor ramps upwards as a result. I think you may have cause and effect the wrong way round.

Comment: In 2)Isn't there a switching loss wherein as current slowly increases then voltage is slowly decreasing(then area below intersection is power loss) ? In hardswitching that always happens, but I don't get why in this circuit, the voltage is already zero and even stays in zero even if current is slowly increasing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How soft-switching works in these circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504340/how-soft-switching-works-in-these-circuit)

Comment: No, I'm the one who also asked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extracted the full picture from your link it would impart more information (I have added the definition of FWD and written it in purple so as not to confuse). I've also re-arranged it to make it easier to follow: -

[image]

1. Inductor current ramps upwards when IGBT turns on (as per \$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}\$). It's slope starts to tail off due to C1 i.e. it isn't a true linear rise like a pure inductor.
2. IGBT turns off and residual energy in the inductor forms a tuned circuit with C1
3. You only get half a cycle of resonance because the diode across the IGBT shunts the negative portion of the sine wave and the IGBT turns on again before it can rise positively again.

In all of the above waveforms, residual voltages like the IGBT on voltage and the forward conduction voltage of the FWD are ignored. They are ignored because they represent a small fraction of the overall waveform voltages.

They shouldn't be ignored when making conduction loss calculations though.

Comment: For example, when I_c is at the **starting 5% of the slope(ramp)**, the Vce is already approximately zero .Why? I mean, if Vce is already zero at that point, then that means the whole voltage is already dropped at the Inductor **even if it is just at the starting 5% of the slope....**. (The current is ramp upwards so I conclude that the voltage at inductor is also ramping up, so I think it's impossible for the Inductor voltage to just shoot at the peak even if current is not yet at the peak). Or was it related to the fact that voltage at inductor leads the current????

Comment: For Ic to charge properly through the inductor the IGBT needs to turn on - it turns on when the voltage is low. When it turns on the current will ramp upwards as shown. The voltage is low because the parallel resonance of L and C1 would produce a decaying sinewave (if the FWD were not present). That decaying sinewave does one half cycle and is clamped by the FWD in the negative half cycle therefore, at that point, the IGBT can switch on. Does that make any more sense because I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Yes. Also, when IGBT turns off, current dropped rapidly but Vce only started sinusoidally rising after the current dropped(approximately). I don't get how resonant circuit LC cause this delay of rise in Vce.(I mean if current shoots rapidly down, the Vce should shoot rapidly upward, too) Was it because of the LC tank that has infinite impedance when parallel causing the LC tank to look as an open circuit thus Vce is still approximately zero even after the current shoots rapidly down?

Comment: When IGBT turns off the inductor current doesn't drop rapidly because it discharges into C1 to form a resonant tank. Have you considered using a simulator to mimic this behaviour? Please be precise in naming this current or that current because I'm here scratching my head and wondering what you are talking about. Look at IL graph - it doesn't drop rapidly. I have no idea how much you know about resonant tank circuits and trying to figure out the one in your question may be a step too far for you at the moment. You shouldn't think in terms of infinite impedances in transient situations.

Comment: Also remember that this isn't a talking shop - it's a question and answer site and if you are having problems understanding the LC role then do some simulations and figure out basic LC current and voltage relationships first.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this in Proteus, but it is always getting error. But I'm talking about I_c: when IGBT turns off, I_c dropped rapidly but Vce only started sinusoidally rising after the current dropped(thus achieved zero current switching). I don't get how resonant circuit LC cause this delay of rise in Vce.(I mean if I_c shoots rapidly down, the Vce should shoot rapidly upward at the same time since its turning off)

Comment: How can Vce shoot rapidly upwards when there is C1 to prevent that from happening. You need to get your sim working. Vce started sinusoidally rising because that's what a parallel LC does when there is residual current in the inductor with nowhere else to go. You really need to get your sim working.